# How to set the max_results value from the gdata.codesearch API higher than 10?

Tags: python, api, gdata

Hi can someone tell me how to use the gdata Codesearch API and augment the number of results from the Query higher than 10 ?

I allready check the CodesearchExample.py from [Code Google Gdata - CodesearchExample](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/browse/samples/codesearch/CodesearchExample.py) , but couldn't find a way to do it.

Anyone got an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use GetSnippetsFeed like the example does. GetSnippetsFeed is actually a wrapper that creates a CodesearchQuery object without any parameters. If you create that object yourself you can set the max_results property.

```
service = gdata.codesearch.service.CodesearchService(source='my_test_app-1.0')
query = gdata.codesearch.service.CodesearchQuery(text_query="search text")
query.max_results=15
feed = service.Query(query.ToUri())
```